# Google Maps intent not showing correct zoom level

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Whenever I launch my Google Maps intent the zoom level doesn't change for some reason. Is this a bug or is there something that I'm not doing correctly?

**Data class**

```
data class MyDataClass(val myCoordinates: String)
```

**Fragment class**

```
...
    val myDetails = myList[position] as MyDataClass

    val myClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
                val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + myDetails.myCoordinates + "?z=8&(Google+Australia)")
                val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
                holder.environsEButton.context.startActivity(mapIntent)


        holder.myButton.context.startActivity(mapIntent)
    }
...
```

**Fragment class**

```
...
    myList.add(MyDataClass("25.5153717,-0.1000000"))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are using Google Maps Intents for Android (not Maps SDK)

May I suggest String interpolation

```
val zoomLevel : Int = 8
val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=${myDetails.myCoordinates}&z=${zoomLevel}&(Google+Australia)")
```

To change the zoom level, you can set the value `zoomLevel` from 0 to 23.
In your `MyDataClass` , you may add the field zoomLevel.

**Edit**: looking closer, your Uri started with `?q`, next parameter should be `?z` instead of `&z`. That's why your zoom was not showing.

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents

Comment: Great, but now the marker is no longer appearing.

Comment: @Swarthy46, the `geo:0,0` are back for the marker

Comment: In this case, both of the answer's aren't that wrong.

Comment: Should it be this? `val gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=${myDetails.myCoordinates}?z=${zoomLevel}(Google+Australia)")`

Answer (score 0):

The zoom is already represented by `z=8`, but the location shoud be: `geo:25.5153717,-0.1000000`. Just see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)... while I'd assume that when passing both, coordinates and a location string, it might pick one of them, not both (as these queries might contradict themselves, in case they won't refer to exactly the same location).

Comment: Both answers are saying 2 completely different things. What does `geo` actually mean?

Comment: `geo` might stand for geo-location, which equals coordinates. and I'd fully agree with the other one answer, that the query-string might have been malformed; these always start with a `?` and further parameters are then concatenated with a `&`.

Comment: It's a shame that the [issue regarding the custom label not showing](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129726279) has still not been fixed after several years. Alternatively I did plan on showing a `MapView` with several markers but I'm trying to avoid the 44K methods limit as I have many different locations to show the most being a dozen markers on a `MapView`. Would using Google Maps Intents for Android (not Maps SDK). use less methods overall due to intents? I'm pretty sure the dependency has many methods (despite being androidx) many I probably don't need.

Comment: I also must add that every 6 months my MapView goes blank for some strange reason causing me to avoid using it. Having to reset my key so often is very annoying.